# Matrix product to keep desired elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Is there a matrix based operation that, given two matrices of type below, transforms

$$
\mathbf{e}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & 0 & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
into

$$
\mathbf{A}'=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & 0 & 0\\
a_{31} & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

i.e., keeps elements of matrix $A$ for which the matrix of 1's-0's had ones, rest become zero.
For instance, the matrix product doesn't do the trick, e.g. in the above case it is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{21}+a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{23}\\
0 & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
0 & a_{12} & a_{13}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is not the desired result, given by $\mathbf A'.$

- Is there a way to perform the transformation $\mathbf A \to \mathbf A'$ given the input matrix $\mathbf e?$ which is always a matrix of $1$'s and $0$'s, whose diagonal is always zero (an example of which given above), and $\mathbf A$ is always non-negatively valued, symmetric, and diagonally always zero.

Comment: The Hadamard product does the trick (and is a pretty obvious solution)

Comment: you want something like matlab's  element-wise product  "e .* A"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called the **Hadamard product** which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).  Essentially what this does is that it is an entry-wise multiplication of matrices, so $A\circ B = [a_{ij}b_{ij}]$.  More broadly, it's defined as

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \ldots & a_{mn} \\
\end{array} \right ] \circ \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & \ldots & b_{1n} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & \ldots & b_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{m1} & b_{m2} & \ldots & b_{mn} \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n}b_{1n} \\
a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n}b_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1}b_{m1} & a_{m2}b_{m2} & \ldots & a_{mn}b_{mn} \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

If you're specifically looking at a Matlab implementation of something, the way to accomplish this would be `A.*B`, but virtually all programming languages will have some built-in function to accomplish this.

Comment: +1, although I would say *entry-wise* rather than *point-wise*.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Will edit.